# Dockerized spring app throws 401s on all endpoints

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, netflix-zuul

I believe I might be making some rookie mistake but here goes.

There are five spring apps, (Discovery server, Auth server, three more for specific purposes). The auth server is configured using Zuul to redirect to others if authenticated, except for login and registration endpoints. The whole thing works as expected while running locally (with Intellij) but gives **401s on all endpoints** when inside docker. All containers are on the same network as the discovery server is picking them up and the other apps (Discovery clients) also show successful registration logs.
Specifically, the auth **server attempts to authenticate even permitted endpoints** when inside docker, which is checking for a JWT token. While it does work with a token, it should however permit the request for the specified endpoints, right?

<s>**UPD1** - Not so sure about the server attempting to authenticate permitted endpoints, but it does return 401 on `permitAll()` endpoints</s>

**UPD3** - So, overriding the `shoudNotFilter` in the `JwtRequestFilter` to return true for permitted endpoints works inside docker but I am having a hard time finding documentation on whether filters need to overridden in this way ? and why does this work without overriding during local run ??

Currently using a single docker-compose file as below

```yaml
version: '3.3'

services:
  mongod:
    container_name: mongod
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/db
      - mongo_config:/data/configdb
  eureka:
    container_name: eureka
    image: myapp.eureka
    ports:
      - 1111:1111
    environment:
      - "JAVA_OPTS=-Dspring.profiles.active=prod"
  auth:
    image: myapp.auth
    ports:
      - 1112:1112
    depends_on:
      - mongod
      - eureka
      - user
    # two more entries
    environment:
      - "JAVA_OPTS=-Dspring.profiles.active=prod"
  user:
    image: myapp.user
    ports:
      - 1113:1113
    depends_on:
      - mongod
      - eureka
    environment:
      - "JAVA_OPTS=-Dspring.profiles.active=prod"
  # Two more services as the user service above

volumes:
  mongo_data:
    external: true
  mongo_config:
    external: true
```

Prod profile (application-prod.yml) configuration is as below -

```yaml
server:
  port: 1112

spring:
  application:
    name: auth-service
  data:
    mongodb:
      host: mongod
      port: 27017
      database: myappdb

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka:1111/eureka/
  instance:
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 30

zuul:
  routes:
    user-service:
      path: /user/**
      url: http://user:1113
      stripPrefix: true
    # skipped other services
```

The application-dev.yml is also the same as above with `localhost` instead of service names after the `http://` part
WebSecurityConfigurer class -

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private AuthEntryPoint entryPoint;
  private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
  private JwtRequestFilter requestFilter;

  WebSecurityConfig(AuthEntryPoint entryPoint, JwtUserDetailsService userDetailsService, JwtRequestFilter requestFilter) {
    this.entryPoint = entryPoint;
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.requestFilter = requestFilter;
  }

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
  }

  @Bean
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Bean
  public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
        .cors().and()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/authenticate").permitAll()
      .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user/register").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
      .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint).and().sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
      .and()
        .addFilterBefore(requestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }
}
```

The `requestFilter` used the above checks for JWT token and that is definitely registered, as logs indicate. I don't think this is a dupe as others mostly dealt with configurations not being picked up or the containers not being on the same network.
(Fun fact - Even the dockerized apps worked before adding `dev` and `prod` profiles)

**UPD2** - auth server logs

```term
auth_1    | Setting Active Processor Count to 8
auth_1    | Adding $JAVA_OPTS to $JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
auth_1    | WARNING: Container memory limit unset. Configuring JVM for 1G container.
auth_1    | Calculated JVM Memory Configuration: -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -Xmx400305K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=136270K -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -Xss1M (Total Memory: 1G, Thread Count: 250, Loaded Class Count: 21645, Headroom: 0%)
auth_1    | Adding 127 container CA certificates to JVM truststore
auth_1    | Spring Cloud Bindings Enabled
auth_1    | Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.security.properties=/layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/java-security-properties/java-security.properties -agentpath:/layers/paketo-buildpacks_bellsoft-liberica/jvmkill/jvmkill-1.16.0-RELEASE.so=printHeapHistogram=1 -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=8 -Dspring.profiles.active=prod -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -Xmx400305K -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=136270K -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -Xss1M -Dorg.springframework.cloud.bindings.boot.enable=true
auth_1    | 
auth_1    |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
auth_1    |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
auth_1    | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
auth_1    |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
auth_1    |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
auth_1    |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
auth_1    |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.3.RELEASE)
auth_1    | 
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:16.909  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.car.auth.AuthServer                  : The following profiles are active: prod
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:20.066  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data MongoDB repositories in DEFAULT mode.
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:20.484  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 401ms. Found 1 MongoDB repository interfaces.
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:20.940  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'service-registry' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:21.016  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'hystrix.stream' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:21.853  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=81aa2da8-bbc8-3347-98a9-e2f9917de93c
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:24.534  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 1112 (http)
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:24.613  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:24.613  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.37]
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:24.960  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:24.961  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 7887 ms
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:25.557  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:25.558  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:25.629  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory  : DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@4d7a64ca
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:26.381  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[mongod:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:26.743  INFO 1 --- ['}-mongod:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:7}] to mongod:27017
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:26.766  INFO 1 --- ['}-mongod:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=mongod:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=9, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=19235385}
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:27.118  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.LocalDateTime to class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might want to check your annotation setup at the converter implementation.
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:27.550  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.data.convert.CustomConversions       : Registering converter from class java.time.LocalDateTime to class org.joda.time.LocalDateTime as reading converter although it doesn't convert from a store-supported type! You might want to check your annotation setup at the converter implementation.
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:28.144  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:8}] to mongod:27017
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:30.925  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6d815fb7, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@352f6727, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@5d3f99d7, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@51af8049, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@35dcd032, com.car.auth.components.JwtRequestFilter@4af7dd6a, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@10dfa7ef, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@fabef2e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@376af784, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7bec8cb0, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@2d74cbbd, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@6b2ef50e]
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:31.070  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:31.077  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:31.835  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:33.744  WARN 1 --- [           main] ockingLoadBalancerClientRibbonWarnLogger : You already have RibbonLoadBalancerClient on your classpath. It will be used by default. As Spring Cloud Ribbon is in maintenance mode. We recommend switching to BlockingLoadBalancerClient instead. In order to use it, set the value of `spring.cloud.loadbalancer.ribbon.enabled` to `false` or remove spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon from your project.
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:34.356  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.zuul.ZuulFilterInitializer       : Starting filter initializer
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:34.365  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:34.416  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:34.801  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:34.875  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:34.876  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:35.045  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:35.045  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:35.256  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:35.280  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:35.280  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:35.280  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:35.280  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:35.280  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:35.280  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:35.280  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:35.387  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:35.389  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Starting heartbeat executor: renew interval is: 5
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:35.392  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : InstanceInfoReplicator onDemand update allowed rate per min is 4
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:35.397  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1602062795396 with initial instances count: 0
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:35.402  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application AUTH-SERVICE with eureka with status UP
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:35.403  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Saw local status change event StatusChangeEvent [timestamp=1602062795403, current=UP, previous=STARTING]
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:35.405  INFO 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_AUTH-SERVICE/bc8abb6e4570:auth-service:1112: registering service...
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:35.436  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 1112 (http) with context path ''
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:35.438  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 1112
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:35.476  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.car.auth.AuthServer                  : Started AuthServer in 22.166 seconds (JVM running for 23.761)
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:35.498  INFO 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_AUTH-SERVICE/bc8abb6e4570:auth-service:1112 - registration status: 204
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:47.823  INFO 1 --- [nio-1112-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:47.823  INFO 1 --- [nio-1112-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:47.834  INFO 1 --- [nio-1112-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 11 ms
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:47.922  WARN 1 --- [nio-1112-exec-1] c.car.auth.components.JwtRequestFilter   : JWT Token has expired
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:26:58.092  WARN 1 --- [nio-1112-exec-5] c.car.auth.components.JwtRequestFilter   : JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:27:05.390  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:27:05.390  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:27:05.391  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:27:05.391  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:27:05.391  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:27:05.391  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: false
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:27:05.392  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
auth_1    | 2020-10-07 09:27:05.454  INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : The response status is 200
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you please share error logs ?

Comment: @Amitkumar , added auth server's logs in question, also sent some requests, one with valid token, one expired and another without any token, if that helps.